# Can't open example files in LyX (greyed out)

Tags: finder, filesystem, dialog

I am trying to bring up [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) on a mac. One of the first things in the tutorial is to go look at the file named `example_raw.lyx`.

[image]

I know the file is on my machine because I found it using terminal, i.e., `find / name "example_raw.lyx" -print 2> /dev/null` reveals that the file is in `/Applications/LyX.app/Contents/Resources/examples`.

[image]

But, when I try to open it from the LyX GUI, there doesn't seem to be any way for me to navigate to the folder that contains the file -- everything inside `/Applications` is greyed out and denies any kind of clicking; I tried all thirty-two combinations of option, command, control, shift and double versus single clicking.

[image]

I suspect this is more of a general question concerning the open-dialog on Mac.  I am VERY NEW to the Macintosh GUI even though I know Unix well and Windows well.  I'll take any solution to this problem, either specific or general: a way just to keyboard in the path I want, or some way to click around that will let me get to my stuff, or some LyX-specific solution that gets me access to their examples.

All this user-friendliness is frustrating :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If LyX utilizes the Open File dialog appropriately*, you should be able to visit any path directly via the Finder shortcut <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.  Tab completion works in the resulting path dialog.

*If LyX does not allow browsing via path,* I would just copy the files to a temporary directory to bypass the difficulty.

**Sidebar**
Mac OS is full of very handy keyboard shortcuts that work fairly consistently.  See [this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) for a fairly comprehensive list. Since you're familiar with UNIX, it may help to note *basic* Emacs navigation also works in most text editing contexts--`C-b, C-f,C-a,C-e, C-k, C-y`.